# Unable to attach a reserve static internal IP to a vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**VM-A** is using **network-A**. I want to assign **static-internal-IP-A** for **VM-A**.

/*--Method 1--*/

1. Clicked on **VM-A**
2. Update *network interfaces* **network-A**
3. Under *Internal IP* dropdown option, it shows *Automatic* and *Custom*. (*I do remember seeing the **Create IP** option a couple of times but I can't reproduce the steps to have this option again*)

/*--Method 2--*/

1. Clicked on **network-A**
2. Under *Reserve Static Internal IP Address* tab, reserve **static-internal-IP-A**
3. Repeat steps in Method 1 again
4. The **static-internal-IP-A** option does not show up

Which steps have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a reserved internal IP to an existing compute engine. You have to create another VM or another network interface for this VM.

More detail in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#console)